# Message box pop-up through filter with VBA

Tags: vba, filter, messagebox

I'm looking to have a macro filter through a certain data set (which uses filters) for a certain date. If it doesn't find the date, I'd like a message box to pop-up stating that no transactions were made, and if it does find the date, I'd like it to copy the the entire data set for that date. Here below, I tell it to filter for that date. I have no problem copying the data set, I can't seem to get the message box to pop-up if the date doesn't appear in the filter.

`
    ' Copy New Buys
    Windows("Filename").Activate
        MonthlyBuys.Activate

```
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CN$760").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="SA68"

        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CN$760").AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _

        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "08/20/2013")

        Lastrow = MonthlyBuys.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:CN" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("No New Transactions for" & Now)
            Else
                MonthlyBuys.Range("A2:CN" & Lastrow).Copy
       End If`
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`CountA` counts the number of nonblank cells in the indicated range. When you filter a range, you're not actually deleting the values from that row, so they will be counted in the `CountA` formula as not blank. This is why your `MsgBox` is never hit.

When a filter is executed, the height of the rows that are not shown is changed to 0. If the entire range of data is filtered out (not visible to you), then the height of that range should be 0. Therefore, you should be checking the height of the filtered range instead of counting blank values. Update your `IF` statement from

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:CN" & Lastrow)) = 0 Then
```

to...

```
If Range("A2:CN" & Lastrow).Height = 0 Then
```

Comment: When I input that date(08/20/2013), even though I don't have data for that date, I have data for 08/01/2013. Why is that?

Comment: Try using `CDate("08/20/2013")`